# Show the title of the node from an entity reference

Tags: 7, views

i have a content type, which has in it a field which is of type Entity Reference. I now have created a view, where i need to aggregate on the sum of records based on this field. But my problem is that the view does not show the text that the entity reference field points to, it shows just a number. How could i make the view, show the rendered entity instead of this number?

Answer (score 1):

Add a relationship in your view using the field you do the entity reference with. That will expose all of that entity's fields to be used in the view

Comment: could you please elaborate with some screenshots? i am afraid i am missing some settings, and i cannot make this work

Comment: Have a google there's plenty of resources out there e.g. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/add-a-relationship-to-a-view or there's videos on tutorial sites/youtube